# AltBeacon Minor & Major

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

How can we get minor and major in monitoring mode when beacon is detected (background) ?

I check https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html but didn't find a solution.

Comment: What do you mean you didn't find the solution? The ranging example returns a list of ranged beacons. The beacons have the major and minor.

Comment: I want to detect major and minor when the app is killed.

Comment: You want a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Monitoring APIs do not return the exact identifiers of matched beacons** detected.  They only return a reference to the `Region` object that was used to do the monitoring, and if it contains null values for identifiers (wildcards), then you won't know exactly what beacon identifiers were seen.

When you need to know those identifiers, the standard approach is to **use the ranging API**s triggered by `beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)`.  The callback for these APIs is `didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Region region, Collection<Beacon>)`which gives you a list of every beacon matched in the last scan interval.

You can see examples of how to use ranging in the same samples page here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: Is there a reason why it doesn't return the exact identifiers? Monitoring is a great feature, but pretty useless if I can't find out which beacon was received.

Comment: There are lots of reasons for this, but perhaps the most important is that the API is designed to be interoperable with the CoreLocation API on iOS, and that is how it works there.  On that platform, combining ranging and monitoring is the way you get around the limitation.   It would be possible to augment the Android Beacon Library to have a hybrid callback that provides this additional info.  If you are interested in this feature please feel free to open an issue on the library open source repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample code.Ranging Example Code.Listed beacons major,minor ex. [this](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

Answer (score 0):

This library looks like a generalized form of beacon detection library. It is not intended only for iBeacons. So you can not get Major and Minor dirctly. But there is a beacon parser class which can be used to accomplished to fulfill this task.[Link](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/javadoc/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconParser.html)
Example:

```
 BeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
  .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```